# Right align menu labels in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, right-to-left, wxformbuilder

I want my GUI be right-to-left (for arabic, persian, etc). Using single line code below makes some magic there

```
    self.SetLayoutDirection(wx.Layout_RightToLeft)
```

Now Menus in MenuBar are right aligned and that how it should be. But it is not enough. I want MenuBarItem labels to be right aligned but above code is not enough. I tried wxformbuilder to do the job but failed.

How can I do that?

Comment: In wxMSW ther is no problem and SetLayoutDirection does the job but in linux I have that problem